# Usecase of Spring DAO

Tags: spring, dao

I'm wondering what is the typical usecase of Spring DAO where we can easily switch between different persistence frameworks.

Apart from abstracting the boiler-plate code (for JDBC, Hibernate like) Why does any application want to change its ORM frameworks so frequently?

Answer (score 2):

By using a DAO pattern with a distinct DAO interface, this enables you to mock the DAO implementation. With this you improve testability of your code, as you are then able to write tests that do not need database access.

It is not only about frequently being able to switch between ORM frameworks, but is also about reducing effort if you are *enforced* to change the ORM.

Another reason is, that you might have different data sources like a database, a webservice or the file system for example. In this case you don't abstract the ORM but simply the persistence mechanism in general.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real important idea behind DAOs are that you have just one spot where all data access related code for a particular entity ist located. That makes testing and refactoring of your persistence layer easier and your code is better readable.

Furthermore, it makes the code better readable. Think of a new developer in your team that should implement a feature. If she needs to access the databasase she would look into the dao for data access methods. 
If you scatter the data access code in different services the risk is pretty high that someone produces code duplicates.